# create event chain after running all Start methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get into developing an event driven game. At first I created a singleton with a bunch of events, for example all events related to the current level.

```
public class LevelEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LevelEvents instance;

    public event Action onLevelRead;
    public event Action onLevelSerialized;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void LevelRead()
    {
        if (onLevelRead != null)
        {
            onLevelRead();
        }
    }

    public void LevelSerialized()
    {
        if (onLevelSerialized != null)
        {
            onLevelSerialized();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create an event chain from reading the level file up to serializing the level. So these events seem to be pretty straight forward.

[image]

My LevelReader is the entry point and dispatches an event after reading the file.

```
public class LevelReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += ReadLevelFile;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= ReadLevelFile;
    }

    private void ReadLevelFile(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
    {
        // not implemented yet
        LevelEvents.instance.LevelRead();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The serializer will listen to the event and serializes the level. After that, it will dispatch the serialized event for next scripts

```
public class LevelSerializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        LevelEvents.instance.onLevelRead += SerializeLevel;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        LevelEvents.instance.onLevelRead -= SerializeLevel;
    }

    private void SerializeLevel()
    {
        // not implemented yet
        LevelEvents.instance.LevelSerialized();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So there is a problem. The reader dispatches the read event after the scene has loaded. The serializer will listen to this event on start. This is too late, the serializer will not receive a notification. I can't use Awake because this is required for the event singleton registration (LevelEvents).

I thought about not listening for the sceneLoaded event and call the ReadLevelFile method in the Start method. This is still too late, because the Start method of the LevelReader gets fired and the Serializer will still not receive a notification.

How can I run the ReadLevelFile method after every Start method was fired? I am hoping to get a better solution than my approaches:

- Invoke this method after X seconds (timers are dangerous)
- Run the Update method once (bad solution I think)
- Write a system that keeps track of every EventSubscriber and fires the first method after every EventSubscriber launched its Start method (too much logic for this, no?)
- Define an script execution order (bad solution I think)

Comment: When each of these scripts will become alive?

Comment: Could you carry over the LevelSerializer from the previous scene using DontDestroyOnLoad?

Comment: @ dedecos all of them become alive the same time

Comment: @ Nicklas I could, but should I? I think each level should have its own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html#BeforeTheFirstFrameUpdate)...

> Start is called before the first frame update only if the script instance is enabled.

Based on that, you can use a coroutine to wait until the next frame on start like so:

```
public class LevelReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ReadLevelFileAfterFirstFrameCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator ReadLevelFileAfterFirstFrameCoroutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        // Call read level file.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just make sure the script instance is actually enabled as the doc states.
If you need to, you can call the coroutine in `Awake` too. It will run after all `Awake` and `Start` has been called.